# callback of chrome.tabs.setZoom hasn't been called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension - my code below :

**content scripts**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('someId', proportion, function () {
    console.log('called!');
});
```

**background script**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (proportion, sender, callBack) {

    chrome.tabs.setZoom(sender.tab.id, proportion, function () {
        callBack();
    });
});
```

The `callBack` should be called after setZoom is done, but it didn't.

If I change background script code like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (proportion, sender, callBack) {

    chrome.tabs.setZoom(sender.tab.id, proportion, function () {
    });
    callBack();
});
```

The callBack has been called, and console output `called!`.

Comment: _Please_ do not use SO snippets for extension code. Code should simply be formatted by 4 space indent.

Comment: Basically, the above answers your question perfectly.